# Create macos app with EULA screen

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to create a macos app (example.app) with EULA screen. Don't want a .dmg, as I want to run the app directly. Clicking on the app will show the EULA screen and then launch it.

Is there any way I can do that? Please help.

Comment: What do you need to know besides improvising a window showing it?

Answer (score 0):

Make another window in your XIB. Link/connect the new window to your AppDelegate.m file with a new property EULAwindow. Make sure both windows are set to be not visible at launch.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *EULAwindow;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    BOOL hasUserAgreedToEULA = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"userHasAgreedEULA"];
    if (hasUserAgreedToEULA) {
        [self showAppWindow];
    } else {
        [[self EULAwindow] orderFront:nil];
    }
}

- (IBAction)userAgreesAction:(NSButton *)sender {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"userHasAgreedEULA"];
    [[self EULAwindow] close];
    [self showAppWindow];
}

- (IBAction)userDisagreesAction:(NSButton *)sender {
    [NSApp terminate:nil];
}

- (void)showAppWindow
{
    [[self window] orderFront:nil];
}
```

[image]